# Using jq to get a structured output

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json as my input for jq processing

```
[
    {
        "Category": "Disk Partition Details",
        "Filesystem": "udev",
        "Size": "3.9G",
        "Used": 0,
        "Avail": "3.9G",
        "Use%": "0%",
        "Mounted": "/dev"
    },
    {
        "Category": "Disk Partition Details",
        "Filesystem": "tmpfs",
        "Size": "799M",
        "Used": "34M",
        "Avail": "766M",
        "Use%": "5%",
        "Mounted": "/run"
    }
]
```

using  `./csvtojson.sh bb.csv | jq 'map( {(.Category): del(.Category)})'` as suggested by [@peak here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059107/how-do-i-add-parent-keys-in-jq), I've reached till the json below

```
  [
  {
    "Disk Partition Details": {
      "Filesystem": "udev",
      "Size": "3.9G",
      "Used": 0,
      "Avail": "3.9G",
      "Use%": "0%",
      "Mounted": "/dev"
    }
  },
  {
    "Disk Partition Details": {
      "Filesystem": "tmpfs",
      "Size": "799M",
      "Used": "34M",
      "Avail": "766M",
      "Use%": "5%",
      "Mounted": "/run"
    }
  }
]
```

All I want is to put the category on the top for once only and to break this json to another level as i did in the previous step like this.

```
[
  {
    "Disk Partition Details": {
      "udev" :{
      "Size": "3.9G",
      "Used": 0,
      "Avail": "3.9G",
      "Use%": "0%",
      "Mounted": "/dev"
      },

      "tmpfs" : {
      "Size": "799M",
      "Used": "34M",
      "Avail": "766M",
      "Use%": "5%",
      "Mounted": "/run"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I think it might be easier if you took the original CSV and used Python to create JSON output directly in the desired format.

Comment: Thanks, I agree this is easy in python. It's for learning how jq actually works.

Comment: The final JSON would be a bit difficult to work with. You would have to know to look in _either_ `udev` or `tmpfs` to get at the `Size`.  It would be easier to query the JSON in the format it is at the top.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Kusalananda The json used above is just a sample here for understanting the usage of jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete **`jq`** solution:

```
jq '[ group_by(.Category)[0] | .[0].Category as $k 
      | { ($k): (reduce .[] as $o 
                    ({}; .[($o.Filesystem)] = ($o | del($o.Category, $o.Filesystem)))
                ) 
        } 
    ]' input.json
```

In case if `"Filesystem"` key could be a number - change `.[($o.Filesystem)]` to the following `.[($o.Filesystem | tostring)]`

---

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Disk Partition Details": {
      "udev": {
        "Size": "3.9G",
        "Used": 0,
        "Avail": "3.9G",
        "Use%": "0%",
        "Mounted": "/dev"
      },
      "tmpfs": {
        "Size": "799M",
        "Used": "34M",
        "Avail": "766M",
        "Use%": "5%",
        "Mounted": "/run"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working perfectly fine. But it won't work if a value in Filesystem column is a number. It is throwing an error as jq: error (at <stdin>:83): Cannot index object with number.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, see my notation

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the numeric values are also working fine. 

But why it is giving me unique rows only?
It would be a great help if you would explain it to me.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, read about `group_by()` function: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#group_by(path_expression)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing yourself a disservice rearranging your JSON in this way.

The original JSON looks fine to me.

With that, if you'd like to get all the sizes for `udev` filesystems you would do

```
jq '.[] | select(.Filesystem == "udev").Size' file.json
```

A simple operation like that on the reorganized file would be

```
jq '.[] | ."Disk Partition Details".udev.Size' file1.json
```

The rearranged file furthermore only supports one mountpoint per filesystem type as far as I can see. If you had several `tmpfs` filesystems, then I don't know where you would put them.

Comment: As mentioned above, The json used above is just a sample here for understating the usage of jq. Roman answer serves it very well. Thanks for your comments though.